# Why eclipse market place is not downloading?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am using eclipse juno my eclipse market place is not working well problem with downloading a plugins and software?

If I am install new software means it has error on downloading.

Comment: you need to install your organization's root ssl certificate to jre which eclise is using. refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39075967/1802348) answer for installing certificate to JRE

Answer (score 0):

The first place to check would be proxy settings. If you are behind a proxy you need to configure proxy fist under Window (or Eclipse on Mac) - Preferences - General - [Network Connections](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-net-preferences.htm).