# PKIX path building failed in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, liferay, pkix

i'm working with Liferay and i'm using eclipse, and running a client/server model, using an encrypted socket (SSL).

Currently, my application is running the client/server connection ok when I run the application in batch mode but when i try to start the server in Eclipse the application is giving me error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
```

I already use the InstallCert.java and copy the jssecacerts into

> %JAVA_HOME%/jdk_version/jre/lib/security

but is still giving me errors. I've also checked the certificate (keytool -v -list) and installed manually in the root CAs trusted. What can be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411410/1802348) answer for your reference.

No need of passing any VM arguments after you successfully installed certificate of the site which is giving you PKIX error!

But key is to find JRE which is giving you this error! So make sure about 2 things:

1. you install certificate to `cacerts` file of JRE which Eclipse is using
2. certificate is root certificate

Comment: my certificate was a root certificate, but i needed to add in the jre, i use portecle for that and that works! thx!

Comment: related: https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Answer (score 5):

tried and tested method. if you face this certificate issue with eclipse plugin installation do below steps:

1. note the url of the plugin site you are facing issue.
2. hit that url in browser.
3. go to lock symbol on left side and click to view certificate
4. go to details and do file export in Base 64.
5. better to save cert in eclipse directory.
6. open cmd with administrator
7. go to jdk directory you are using to run eclipse and find keytool
8. run below command
   `keytool -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts -import -alias example2 -file <path_to_expotrted cert in step 4>`
   use password - changeit
9. go to eclipse.ini and add below commands
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\lib\security\cacerts
10. make sure to restart eclipse after every plugin site certificate added to keystore.

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED: Certificate issue with eclipse plugin installation Follow these steps:

Understand eclipse uses JRE certs to connect. So you need to add your plugin(website) certificates to JRE/lib/security/cacerts

1. Open the URL or your plugin in browser and click below

[Link Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXhPM.png)

[Get Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbl0a.png)

[Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX78c.png)

[Save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfID9.png)

Save it as .cer file

2. Goto your JRE path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_333\lib\security and open command promt here and enter the command
   keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias marketPlaceAPI -file "C:\Users**\Downloads\Programs\marketPlaceAPI.cer"

[Enter Keystore command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8etb.png)

3. Goto your Eclipse Ini file: and under -VmArgs add
   [Update Eclipse.ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0kND.png)

This is all, your certificates are added in JRE and in eclipse you have said to use these certs.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the certifacate path in VM arguments when running in eclipse

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="PATH_TO_jssecacerts"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in my eclipse after struggling for almost a day.
Please find solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73034945/7611709

Answer (score 0):

Adding below lines worked for me.
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "NUL");
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "Windows-ROOT");