# JMeter - Failed to load the plugin manager

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to install a plugin from the plugin manager and I did the installation by downloading a file and kept in the lib\ext folder and restarted the JMeter and I clicked on the option from the tools menu and clicked on the plugins manager it shows an error.

> > javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> > at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)

For the screenshot please follow to this link

[SSL error when opening plugin manager in Jmeter 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757131/ssl-error-when-opening-plugin-manager-in-jmeter-3)

Comment: As per my understanding that firewall is blocking to install the plugin manager. i tried to install plugin manager with different network and it went well.

Comment: you need to install your network root ssl cert to java cacerts which jmeter is using. User [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39075967/1802348) answer for reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify your local truststore in this file: %jmeter_home%\bin\system.properties

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_191\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

Comment: On mac, when jmeter is installed thru homebrew, the location of the system.properties file is /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.6.2/libexec/bin/system.properties

Answer (score 0):

Go to Options: SSL Manager --> Just Add the SSL Certificate to your Test.
SSL Certificate should be stored at :jmeter/bin/ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA

Issue will be Resolved