# I can't sign in to azure to publish my app with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

I need to deploy my app in azure platform with eclipse; When I sign in, this error occurs:
[image: sign in error]

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to your certificate issue. Whenever Java attempts to connect to another application over SSL (e.g.: HTTPS, IMAPS, LDAPS), it will only be able to connect to that application if it can trust it. The way trust is handled in the Java world is that you have a keystore (typically `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`), also known as the truststore. This contains a list of all known Certificate Authority (CA) certificates, and Java will only trust certificates that are signed by one of those CAs or public certificates that exist within that keystore.

You could try below solutions:

1.Make sure you have imported the public certificate of the target instance into the truststore according to the Connecting to [SSL Services instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/connecting-to-ssl-services-802171215.html).

2.Make sure any certificates have been imported into the correct truststore.

3.Check to see that the correct truststore is in use. If -`Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` has been configured, it will override the location of the default truststore, which will need to be checked.

In addition, you could refer to the related threads:

1.[PKIX path building failed in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38844061/pkix-path-building-failed-in-eclipse)

2.["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

Hope it helps you.

---

Just for summary, it's related to the `build path` in the eclipse. Please make sure it's `JDK/JRE` path, not `JRE` path.

Comment: Thank you for your response, in fact the problem was in the build path : I was selecting the JRE. the solution was to replace it with JDK/JRE path ! 
But now I have a different problem, I get http error 404 when my app is published. It's a web service (RESTful). Any idea?

Comment: @Safae You're welcome,I summarized your solution in the answer.You could mark it for others' references on the forum,thank you !

Comment: Yes sure. please do you have any idea about error 404 ? i can't access the app ...

Comment: @Safae Any screenshot? Are you sure your access url is right.

Comment: I can't add screenshots in comment.

Comment: @Safae You could update it in your question.However,I suggest you ending this case and creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

when my app is published, it's a RESTful web service called "RESTfulExample2"
when  I access the default url I get this:
[error http 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C6XP.png)

I don't know what's wrong
here are the screenshots of the variables:
[environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gB8W.png)

Comment: @JayGong here are the screenshots

Comment: Not sure the specific situation on your side.You could check log on the kudu. Kudu url is <your app name>.scm.azurewebsites.com. Please provide more log info.Thank you.

Comment: No not yet, I still can't sign in. I created all the project from the start, but now even with the solution i proposed I still can't access. I tried to get the certificate of the login page to azure portal and do as you said in your first comment ... but it didn't work