# Cannot install cvsedit plugin for eclipse (PKIX path building failed...)

Tags: eclipse, https

In eclipse: Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)

I am trying to install:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/csv-edit-resurrector

using this URL/Update site:
https://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/csvedit/

But I get the following error:

```
Unable to read repository at https://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/csvedit/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/csvedit/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Any suggestion how to fix? Or simply configure in eclipse to "allow all" (ignore certificates)?

[image]

I have also tried using:
https://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/

gives similar error:

```
Unable to read repository at https://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

And I also tried (non https):

http://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/csvedit/

gives similar error:

```
Unable to read repository at http://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/csvedit/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/csvedit/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

In my eclipse.ini I have:

```
...
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.inst
...
```

Comment: Use the update site [`https://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/`](https://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/).

Comment: gives the same error

Comment: I see. The root cause seems to be the `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException`. Which JRE do you use to run Eclipse? As a workaround in this particular case you can use a non-HTTPS update site: [`http://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/csvedit/`](http://nodeclipse.github.io/updates/csvedit/) (`http://...` instead of `https://...`).

Comment: I also tried that and it fails with similar error, see updated post that also has details in jre

Comment: [As far as I know](https://eclipsehowl.wordpress.com/2018/03/09/hello-openj9-on-windows-i-didnt-expect-you-so-soon/), in OpenJDK <=9 the certificate authority (CA) certificates are missing. Unfortunately, `http://nodeclipse.github.io` seems to redirect to HTTPS so that the workaround does not work. Could you try a different Java VM to run Eclipse?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/676

Comment: Hm last comment in that post mentions that it should be fixed in 8u192. I just tried with that update and same error. I will find another plugin for this.

Comment: It should be fixed in the 8u192 OpenJ9 OpenJDK, but maybe not in the HotSpot OpenJDK which is more common.

Comment: you need to install your network root certificate to your jre cacerts file. make sure it is root SSL certificate and refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39075967/1802348) post as a reference if needed.