# PKIX Sun Certification issues with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, certificate, pkix

My Eclipse (2020-03 - Running on Windows 10) was working perfectly. Then suddenly my company updated policies and absolutelly nothing more worked.
I keep getting:

```
Unable to read repository at https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2023-03/202303091200/content.xml.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
```

NOTHING works anymore. Build, Compile, even the MarketPlace returns this error.
I tried a LOT of solutions in SO like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465077/11703579), but none worked.
Added the certificate manually, updated policy, disabled company firewall (with the own company support).

When compiling, I even manually download each maven dependency and pom to the right place, so I could "bypass" the dep download, but didn´t work.

I manage to resolve it with the bellow answer. I am leaving it here to help someone in need like me in the future. (I spent 3 days trying to solve this issue).

Answer (score 0):

The thing that did the trick for me, is describet in this [thread](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=577809).

Basically:

use the windows trust store by providing by adding the following option in `eclipse.ini`:

`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT`

It ensures that eclipse uses all Windows Trusted SSL Certificates, and in my case, the issue is gone.

Hope it helps someone.

Thanks.